# Editor for programming ML on windows?

Tags: ide, functional-programming, editor, ml

I know I can use Emacs but I haven't used it earlier... are there any other alternatives??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) programmer's editor can be easily configured for almost any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Visual Studio editor for [F#](http://fsharp.net) - with

```
#indent "off"
```

at the top of the file, the core of F# is largely compatible with OCaml (especially if you reference the F# PowerPack).  Not perfect, but useful...

Anecdote: a friend of mine was taking a programming class that used OCaml, and he used F# inside VS (sticking to OCaml library/language) to author his homework, to have good editor/debugger support while working, and then switched to OCaml compiler for final touch-ups and compatibility fixes before submitting assignments; this seemed to work reasonably well for him.

Answer (score 2):

Of course... VIM --what i use with ocaml.

Aside from that, there is an eclipse plug-in for SML/NJ called [ML-Dev](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~narain/projects/mldev/) and [ODT](http://ocamldt.free.fr/) for ocaml.